# Retrive From image server to client in postgresql database

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql

I am storing an image using `l_oid` (postgresql). Now i want know convert `l_oid` to `bytea` and `bytea` to image in front end(vb.net)

[note: [i dont want to use `lo_import` and `lo_export` because i need this in client server application]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312498/using-copy-with-binary-for-lo-export-in-postgresql-on-server-system)

can anybody having solution to solve this?

Comment: Usually when working with large objects you use native client driver extensions to call `lo_read`. If you're using nPgSQL you should read http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html and look at the "large objects" section. It's C# code but the example should give you an idea of how to do it in VB.net. The second example is about exactly what you want to do. If you're *not* using npgsql - say you're connected via ODBC or ADO - then it's going to be harder.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have tested your solution, its working fine, can you make your comment as an answer? so that i could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL function loread( integer integer ) to read BLOB's as bytea's.
  You can retrieve or insert byteas using Npgsql
  or   write a UDF to convert the bytea  to Base64 format and return those as text